# How to reopen a closed window?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, viewmodellocator

I switch `ShutdownMode` in my app to `OnExplicitShutdown` so when I close window, my app still working and I try to reopen window like this:

```
new MainWindow().Show;
```

But I've got following error: `Set property '...ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel' threw an exception.` and `InnerException` is: `'AutoWireViewModel' property was already registered by 'ViewModelLocator'`

Have you any idea how to fix this?

I use `ViewModelLocator` from `Microsoft.Prism`

Comment: If you close a window you can't "reopen it".  You have to create the window again.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you simply can't re-open a `Window` after it has been closed. However, you can 'pretend' that you can and use a little deception... instead of closing the `Window` in the first place, you could simply hide it, as it can be hidden and re-displayed any number of times:

```
YourWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

You *could* improve this situation slightly perhaps, by attaching an event handler to the [`Window.Closing` Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing(v=vs.110).aspx). This particular event provides a way to cancel the `Close` operation and so at this point, you could hide it instead:

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // Cancel Window closing 
    e.Cancel = true;
    // Hide Window instead
    YourWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

You could alternatively put this functionality inside the `Window` code behind using the [`Window.OnClosing` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.onclosing(v=vs.110).aspx) if you preferred.